# JPA / Hibernate. Постоянные ошибки

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Добрый день, возникла проблема. Пытаюсь сделать проект на JPA Hibernate, но постоянно возникают ошибки именно на этой строке: 
`.createEntityManagerFactory("MusicDb")` 
в классе Main.java. Возможно, кто-то поможет?

P.S: Я - говнокодер, знаю.

**persistence.xml**

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="MusicDb">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/music"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="*****" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>music.org</groupId>
    <artifactId>musicproject2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
       <dependencies>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
               <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
               <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
           </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
            </dependency>
           <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
           <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
           <version>2.3.0</version>
       </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
               <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
               <version>1.0.2</version>
           </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.27</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Main.java**

```
package Entity;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class Main {
    private static EntityManager em;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence
                .createEntityManagerFactory("MusicDb");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
    }
}
```

---

```
квіт. 22, 2018 1:03:00 ПП org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: MusicDb
    ...]
квіт. 22, 2018 1:03:00 ПП org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.5.Final}
квіт. 22, 2018 1:03:00 ПП org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
квіт. 22, 2018 1:03:00 ПП org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
квіт. 22, 2018 1:03:01 ПП org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
квіт. 22, 2018 1:03:01 ПП org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
квіт. 22, 2018 1:03:01 ПП org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/music]
квіт. 22, 2018 1:03:01 ПП org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {password=****, user=root}
квіт. 22, 2018 1:03:01 ПП org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
квіт. 22, 2018 1:03:01 ПП org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
квіт. 22, 2018 1:03:01 ПП org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.processComplementaryTableDefinitions(EntityBinder.java:936)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:824)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3788)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3742)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1410)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:397)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:75)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:78)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at Entity.Main.main(Main.java:12)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас конфликт версий библиотек. Hibernate подтягивает спецификацию JPA 2.1 (`org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api`), в которой у аннотации `Table` есть свойство `indexes`. Но вы в `pom.xml` подтягиваете спецификацию JPA 1.0 (`javax.persistence:persistence-api`), в которой у аннотации `Table` такого свойства нет. Отсюда проблема - Hibernate ожидает `Table` из JPA 2.1, а у вас в classpath первым попадается `Table` из JPA 1.0. Уберите зависимость `javax.persistence:persistence-api`, и это проблема уйдёт.

Comment: спасибо за попытку но не помогло(

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте файл `persistence.xml` - мой вариант выглядит немного иначе:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="MusicDb" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.entities.User</class>
        <class>com.entities.Group</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/music"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="sudeikin1996"/>

            <property name="hibernate.default_catalog" value="defaultSchema" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: спасибо но не помогло(

Comment: Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: MusicDb] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory

Comment: такая же ошибка....как и предыдущая